# "Unfulfilled dependency at run time":error while creating dynamic depenency

Tags: python, luigi

As I'm trying to create Luigi task classes from a list that includes variables containing class name, file name, and "depend_task" class (ie. another class that this class depends on), I get the above runtime error.

The challenge is that the class definition should include the definition of the "depend_task" class that is being defined at the same time.  Below is my failed attempt and the error message.

Your help will be appreciated.

```
class BDX_Query_0XX(SQLTask):
    acctDate = luigi.Parameter()
    ssisDate = luigi.Parameter() 
    runDesc = luigi.Parameter()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BDX_Query_0XX, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # if self.trans_id is None:
        self.trans_id =  "00902_BDX_Query_0XX" + "__" + self.runDesc  # static.


    def run(self):
        YY = self.acctDate[:4]
        MM = self.acctDate[4:6]
        acctDate = self.acctDate
        ssisDate = self.ssisDate
        runDesc = self.runDesc
        bdx_sql = r'r:\\1.SQL\\BDX_SQL\\'
        cmdList = [
                ('BDX010',f'{bdx_sql}BDX_001_NI_DM 010.sql -o output010.txt',None),
                ('BDX020',f'{bdx_sql}BDX_001_NI_DM 020.sql -o output020.txt','BDX010'),
               ('BDX022a',f'{bdx_sql}BDX_022_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 010.sql -o output022a.txt','BDX020'),
            ('BDX022b',f'{bdx_sql}BDX_022_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 020.sql -o output022b.txt -v Year1={YY} MM={MM}','BDX022a'),
            ('BDX022c',f'{bdx_sql}BDX_022_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 030.sql -o output022c.txt -v Year={YY} Month={MM}', 'BDX022b'),
            ('BDX023',f'{bdx_sql}BDX_023_P031_MTD_All_Final_CatAdj.sql -o output023.txt ','BDX020'),
            ('BDX024',f'{bdx_sql}BDX_024_P031_ITD_All_Final_CatAdj.sql -o output024.txt','BDX020'),
            ('BDX025a',f'{bdx_sql}BDX_025_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 010.sql -o output025a.txt','BDX020'),
            ('BDX025b',f'{bdx_sql}BDX_025_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 020.sql -o output025b.txt -v Year={YY} Month={MM}','BDX025a'),
            ('BDX025c',f'{bdx_sql}BDX_025_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 030.sql -o output025c.txt -v YYMM={acctDate}','BDX025b')
            ]

        tasks = []
        for queryKey, queryCmd, dependQry in cmdList:
            class_name = queryKey
            klass = type(queryKey, (BDX_Task,),{}) 

            **#>>>> ERROR OCCURS IN THE FOLLOWING LINE >>>>>>>**
            tasks.append(klass(acctDate=self.acctDate, ssisDate =self.ssisDate, queryKey = queryKey, queryCmd = queryCmd, runDesc = self.runDesc, dependQry = dependQry)) # this addes Task class named after queryKey to dependency
        yield tasks

        self.get_target().touch()



class BDX_Task_Base(SQLTask):
    acctDate = luigi.Parameter()
    ssisDate = luigi.Parameter(default=None)
    queryKey = luigi.Parameter()
    queryCmd = luigi.Parameter()
    runDesc = luigi.Parameter()
    dependQry = luigi.Parameter()


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BDX_Task_Base, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # if self.trans_id is None:
        self.trans_id = f"00903_BDX_Query_{self.queryKey}__{self.runDesc}"


class BDX_Task(BDX_Task_Base):

    def requires(self):
        dependQry = self.dependQry
        if dependQry:
            if type(dependQry) is str:   # class name in string, then convert to SQLTask here; 
                depend_class= type(dependQry, (BDX_Task_Base,), {} )
                depend_task = [depend_class(acctDate = self.acctDate,ssisDate = self.ssisDate, queryKey = self.queryKey, queryCmd = self.queryCmd, runDesc = self.runDesc, dependQry = self.dependQry)]
            else:
                depend_task =[dependQry(acctDate= self.acctDate, ssisDate = self.ssisDate,queryKey = self.queryKey, queryCmd = self.queryCmd, runDesc = self.runDesc, dependQry = self.dependQry)]
        else:    #class itself
            depend_task = []

        return depend_task

    def run(self):
        print(subprocess.call(self.queryCmd, shell=True))
        self.get_target().touch()
```

Full stack trace

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\luigi\worker.py", line 182, in run
    raise RuntimeError('Unfulfilled %s at run time: %s' % (deps, ', '.join(missing)))
RuntimeError: Unfulfilled dependency at run time: BDX025b_201902_BDX025b_r___1_SQL__BDX_S_7bda6cb3b4



Scheduled 34 tasks of which:
* 20 ran successfully:
    - 2 BDX010(...)
    - 8 BDX020(acctDate=201902, ssisDate=201903, queryKey=BDX022a, queryCmd=r:\\1.SQL\\BDX_SQL\\BDX_022_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 010.sql -o output022a.txt, runDesc=201902 Luigi test1, dependQry=BDX020) ...
    - 2 BDX022a(...)
    - 2 BDX022b(...)
    - 2 BDX025a(...)
    ...
* 10 failed:
    - 1 BDX010(acctDate=201902, ssisDate=201903, queryKey=BDX010, queryCmd=r:\\1.SQL\\BDX_SQL\\BDX_001_NI_DM 010.sql -o output010.txt, runDesc=201902 Luigi test1, dependQry=None)
    - 1 BDX020(acctDate=201902, ssisDate=201903, queryKey=BDX020, queryCmd=r:\\1.SQL\\BDX_SQL\\BDX_001_NI_DM 020.sql -o output020.txt, runDesc=201902 Luigi test1, dependQry=BDX010)
    - 1 BDX022a(acctDate=201902, ssisDate=201903, queryKey=BDX022a, queryCmd=r:\\1.SQL\\BDX_SQL\\BDX_022_P038_All_Final_CatAdj 010.sql -o output022a.txt, runDesc=201902 Luigi test1, dependQry=BDX020)
    - 1 BDX022b(...)
    - 1 BDX022c(...)
    ...
* 4 were left pending, among these:
    * 1 were missing external dependencies:
        - 1 BDX_Query_0XX(acctDate=201902, ssisDate=201903, runDesc=201902 Luigi test1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`BDX_Task` is a subclass of `BDX_Task_Base`. In your init for `BDX_Task_Base`, you have a call to `super(BDX_Task)`... which is `BDX_Task_Base`, so it runs init again, which will again call `super(BDX_Task)` and so on. I assume you intended to write `super(BDX_Task_Base)...`, which will not lead to infinite recursion. As long as you are using a recent enough version of python, `super().__init__(...)` will do the same thing as `super(BDX_Task_Base, self).__init__(...)`.

Comment: oops.. i caught that error and changed the question after that. sorry. Do you have any idea on the revised question?

Comment: Sorry, no idea what's going on here now